# .Split() in a position rather than on a char?

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I have this method to compare the sequence number then increment it by one, using a `.Split('-')` method on a string like this: `CP1-P-CP2-001-A`

```
if (CView.dgvCreate.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    string tempCbl = cblNumber.TrimEnd('-');
    string newCblNum = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in CView.dgvCreate.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[0];
        string[] substring = cell.Value.ToString().Split('-');
        for (int i = 0; i < substring.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
             newCblNum += substring[i] + "-";
        }
        if (newCblNum.TrimEnd('-') == tempCbl)
        {
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(substring[substring.Count() - 1]);
            cblNumber = newCblNum + (i + 1).ToString("D3");
            CView.txtCableNumber.Text = cblNumber;
        }
        else { GenerateCableNumberDb(CView); }
    }

    if (CView.chkParallel.Checked == true)
    {
        ParallelCableNumber(CView);
    }
    else { dataList.Add(cblNumber); }
}
else { GenerateCableNumberDb(CView); }
```

However there is a possibility that the separator (-) will not be there, resulting in the string looking like this: `CP1PCP2001A`.

Also, I should note that the first 3 parts of the string a variable length, only the last 2 parts (Sequence - `001` and Parallel - `A`) are a fixed length, however the `A` on the end might also not be there. Eg. `MOT1PCP2001` is another possibility

I know `Regex` can be used to locate a position in a string, but I'm not sure how I can implement it on this string (or if I even can?)

**EDIT:** I should also note that I have a Boolean to tell me if there is a separator or not, so this (above) method is used if `separator == true`

Comment: Which is the sequence number?

Comment: @hwnd `001`.This will always be in `'D3'` format. The `A` is a duplicate number indication.

Comment: And you are comparing the `001` sequence after you split? Or splitting and just increasing by 1?

Comment: This method cuts off the end of the `newCblNum` (`CP1-P-CP2`) and looks for any other existing strings that are the same number. It then returns the highest number (eg. `CP1-P-CP2-003`) and increments the end number (`003`) by one, then attaches it onto `newCblNum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is probably better to match the substring instead of trying to split in multiple positions.

```
string s = "CP1-P-CP2-001-A";
Match m  = Regex.Match(s, @"\d{3}(?=[A-]|$)");
if (m.Success) {
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value); i += 1;
    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D3")); //=> "002"
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Pity it kinda renders my previous method useless haha, but it definitely is a huge time saver!

Answer (score 1):

Since your string will be fixed length from the tail, that is the way to being matching:

```
(\d{3})(?:-A)?$
```

Use the pattern to match a string ending (matches `$`) with 3 digits (because of `\d{3}`) followed by a possible `-A`. The number will be stored in match group 1 and you can do manipulations on it.

---

I think this is how C# implementation would look:

```
Match m = Regex.Match( cblNumber, @"(\d{3})(?:-A)?$" );
```

Comment: Can you define how I declare this (I'm assuming I use `Regex`?)

Comment: @Ben I'd have to read the C# docs on how regexes are implemented. The above code segment is the regex you can use on the string type variable `cblNumber`.